# Outlook COM Add-In - Show TaskPane in Outlook Compose Window

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, comaddin, addin-express

Config: Outlook 2016, COM Add-In (C# not office.js) -- We are also using Addin-Express' COM library but that's built on top of existing TaskPane in Outlook.

We currently are using the Outlook TaskPane and it works well in Outlook's main window:

[image]

If not obvious, it is dockable (and set to Right) and is visible as users switch between Mail/Appointment/etc.

Please excuse my lack of familiarity in this area.

Does anyone know if it's possible to have the same TaskPane appear in the Outlook Compose window (or Meeting Request window)?

ie:

[image]

Any help/guidance/documentation/even feasibility/LoE is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. When the NewInspector event fires, you add an instance of your task (if necessary) the same way you do that for the regular messages.

Comment: Thank you much that helped a great deal in getting to what I needed

Answer (score 0):

To ensure Outlook Sub-Pane appears in a certain area (when using ADXO1 form), ensure the following are set:

```
this.adxOlFormsCollectionItem1.InspectorLayout = AddinExpress.OL.ADXOlInspectorLayout.RightSubpane;
this.adxOlFormsCollectionItem1.InspectorItemTypes = (AddinExpress.OL.ADXOlInspectorItemTypes)AddinExpress.OL.ADXOlInspectorItemTypes.olMeetingRequest;
```

Which tells Outlook to automatically add the form to selected window (ie. Meeting request/Compose window)